# breqn and \brace

Tags: breqn

I was looking forward to using breqn, but it mysteriously fails with the following piece of code:

```
\begin{dmath*}
    {2 \brace 3}
\end{dmath*}
```

However, this construct outputs a "Missing delimiter" error (`\choose` works without a hitch). What gives?

I'm working with TexLive 2011 on OS X.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\{` has additional code so that it works in text mode as well as math and that upsets `breqn` in the form used here. These infix primitives are rightly deprecated with `amsmath`, but if you must you may:-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\oldlbrace\lbrace
\let\oldrbrace\rbrace
\def\brace{\atopwithdelims\oldlbrace\oldrbrace}
\usepackage{breqn}


\begin{document}
\begin{dmath*}
  {2 \brace 3 }
\end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```